# Не могу объявить массив указателей на класс, который наследуется об абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, классы

Есть класс родитель Function у него есть три наследника Line Cube and Hyperbola.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;


class Function
{
    public :
    virtual void Show() = 0;
    virtual double Value() = 0;

};


class Line : public Function
{
    public :
    double a, b;
    Line(): a(0), b(0) {}
    Line(double a, double b): a(a), b(b) {}
    void Show(double a, double b)
    {
        cout<<"Функция вида: y="<<a<<"x+"<<b<<endl;
    }
    double Value(double a, double b, double x)
    {
        return a*x+b;
    }

};


class Cube : public Function
{
    public :
    double a, b,c;
    Cube(): a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    Cube(double a, double b, double c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
    void Show(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        cout<<"Функция вида: y="<<a<<"xˆ2+"<<b<<"x+"<<c<<endl;
    }
    double Value(double a, double b,double c,double x)
    {
        return a*x*x+b*x+c;
    }

};

class Hyperbola : public Function
{
    public :
    double a;
    Hyperbola(): a(0) {}
    Hyperbola(double a): a(a) {}
    void Show(double a)
    {
        cout<<"Функция вида: y="<<a<<"/x"<<endl;
    }
    double Value(double a,double x)
    {
        if(x!=0)
        {
            return a/x;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"x=0";
            return 0;
        }

    }

};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Введите n"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    Function *arrayCube[n];
    arrayCube[0] = new Hyperbola(1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        double a,b,c;
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        arrayCube[i] = new Cube(a,b,c);
    }
}
```

При объявление массива указателей на это класс не могу присвоить им значения.[image: <code>вот скрин ошибок(работаю в xcode 8</code>]

Comment: Так "не могу объявить", или "объявить могу, но не могу присвоить значения"? Почему в заголовке написано одно, а в тексте - совсем другое?

Answer (score 3):

Ваши классы-наследники реализуют не все чисто-виртуальные методы. Они либо должны реализовывать makeARezalt(), либо он должен быть просто виртуальным, либо вообще не виртуальным.
Кстати, вы забыли про виртуальный деструктор в базовом классе и в наследниках, без него ваши объекты гарантированно будут неправильно удалены.

И если уж вы пишете на c++, используете `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Function>>` для массива указателей.

Edit: Вот вариант решения. Для std::make_unique нужен c++14, но можно создавать объекты просто через new.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>


class UnaryFunction
{
public :
    virtual void show() const = 0;
    virtual double calcValue(double x) const = 0;
    virtual ~UnaryFunction() = default;
};


class LineFunction : public UnaryFunction
{
    double a, b;
public :
    LineFunction(): a(0), b(0) {}
    LineFunction(double a, double b): a(a), b(b) {}
    void show() const override {
        std::cout<<"y="<<a<<"x+"<<b<<std::endl;
    }
    double calcValue(double x) const override{
        return a*x+b;
    }
    ~LineFunction() override = default;

};

class CubeFunction : public UnaryFunction
{
    double a, b,c;
public :
    CubeFunction(): a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    CubeFunction(double a, double b, double c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
    void show() const  override{
        std::cout << "y=" << a << "x^2+" << b << "x+" << c << std::endl;
    }
    double calcValue(double x) const  override{
        return a*x*x+b*x+c;
    }
    ~CubeFunction() override = default;
};

class HyperbolaFunction : public UnaryFunction
{
    double a;
public :
    HyperbolaFunction(): a(0) {}
    HyperbolaFunction(double a): a(a) {}
    void show() const override{
        std::cout<<"y="<<a<<"/x"<<std::endl;
    }
    double calcValue(double x) const override{
        if(x!=0){
            return a/x;
        }
        else{
            throw std::invalid_argument{"division by 0"};
        }
    }
    ~HyperbolaFunction() = default;
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    volatile double x = 12;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UnaryFunction>> functions;
    functions.push_back(std::make_unique<LineFunction>(1, 2));
    functions.push_back(std::make_unique<HyperbolaFunction>(3));
    functions.push_back(std::make_unique<CubeFunction>(15, 2, 4));
    functions.push_back(std::make_unique<LineFunction>(18, 12));
    try{
        for(auto&& function: functions){
            function->show();
            std::cout << "     : x = " << x << " => f(x)=" << function->calcValue(x) << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
        functions.push_back(std::make_unique<HyperbolaFunction>(3));
        functions.back()->show();
        functions.back()->calcValue(0);
    } catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю, что сигнатура Show должна быть одинаковой во всех реализациях

Comment: Да, ошибку я заметил, функцию  makeARezalt() переиминовал в Value как и в наследниках. Но это не помогло. А Show по заданию не может быть одинаковой, в этом и суть Show.

Comment: @GlebNazemnov вы неправильно понимаете смысл виртуальных функций. Можно считать, что базовый класс содержит указатели на виртуальные функции, когда вы создаете наследников, этим указателям присваиваются специфичные для наследника значения. Но для этого сигнатура виртуальных функций в базовом классе и в наследниках должна совпадать. Конкретно в вашем случае в метод show и в метод value можно передавать массив значений (std::vector<double>), так как количество аргументов меняется.

Comment: @GlebNazemnov: Но можно сделать по-другому: пусть метод show вообще не принимает аргументы, а value принимает только x. А остальные значения пусть задаются в конструкторах классов, или специальными методами set_a, set_b и т.д., при этом эти методы не должны быть виртуальными, т.к. относятся к конкретному классу.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а почему лучше использовать std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Function>> ?

Comment: @ТимурМашарипов , т.к. классы полиморфные, их нужно хранить по указателю, т.к. их размер неизвестен. Чтобы не забыть удалить объект, оборачиваем указатели в  unique_ptr, который удалит объект при своем собственном удалении (что, в свою очередь, произойдет при удалении вектора).  unique_ptr особенно полезен при возникновении исключений. С вектором, думаю, понятно - количество аргументов функции может быть разным.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши классы остаются абстрактными, ибо вы не реализуете чисто виртуальные функции:

```
class Function
{
    public :
    virtual void Show() = 0;
    virtual double Value() = 0;

};
```

У вас нет реализаций `double Value();`, вы передаете в них параметры - значит, сигнатуры разные, так что...

Я бы на вашем месте делал

```
class Function
{
    public :
    virtual double Value(double x) const = 0;
    virtual ~Function(){}    
};
```

Ну, а наследники должны реализовывать соответствующую функцию, типа

```
class Cube : public Function
{
    double a, b,c;
    public:
    Cube(double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0, double c = 0.0): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
    double Value(double x) const
    {
        return (a*x+b)*x+c;
    }
    ~Cube(){}
};
```

Ну вот на фига вы передавали в `Value()` значения `a`, `b` и `c`?... Если вы их храните в классе?